# What are the dimensions of the house in this picture?

Tags: middle-ages

What are the approximate dimensions of [The Yeomans' House, Bignor, West Sussex, England](https://www.britishlistedbuildings.co.uk/101026557-the-yeomans-house-bignor#.W1wcvPZFwuU)?

[image]

Comment: How "approximate" are you happy with? You can take a guess at the stone base at 3-4ft, the upper and lower storeys at ~6ft each and the roof at about 10-12ft. Front to back 12-15ft and the frontage 35-40ft.

Comment: Some quick& dirty google maps measurements suggest that the roof is 7*20 meters.

Comment: Bananas were not available in that time period in England. We'll just never know.

Comment: @Schwern It seems you are correct. The house is from the Tudor period, late 1400s, while the [first](http://theconversation.com/the-day-bananas-made-their-british-debut-94742) recorded banana appearance in England was on April 10th, 1633!

Answer (score 4):

From [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.9207409,-0.6018315,313a,35y,270h/data=!3m1!1e3):

[image]

I've positioned the cottage bottom right in the map, against the scale.  You can see that it's roughly 15 m wide and can infer the depth from that.

It's loose and fast, but it's an approximation at least.